# Google Cloud Platform Loadbalancer - ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: load-balancing, redirect, google-cloud-platform, 301-redirect

I am using Google Cloud Platform to host a Wordpress site in a VM.

I am trying to setup a loadbalancer with CDN.

Without the loadbalancer site works fine, there is no http to https redirection setup in apache config or in htaccess.

I have tested the site without loadbalancer and both http and https are working fine without redirection.

Once I enable loadbalancer the site stops working and I get ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error.

Site address is leblonblue.com

Loadbalancer is configured with HTTPS frontend and HTTP backend. There are no host or path rules.

Any ideas on what might be happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the issue by having both backend and front end using HTTPS.

I had tried that before but it did not work. It only worked when I updated the VM instance group port mapping to https only. Before I had two port name mapping entries: http and https. I am not really sure how this impacted but it did...

Answer (score 0):

You should use **Cloud Load Balancing** with **CDN** and not **CDN** by it self. Here's [Official Google Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing)

Comment: I am doing that. I am trying to setup a loadbalancer with CDN.